# Ubuntu reduce video size with ffmepg and change format

Tags: ubuntu, video, ffmpeg, resize, watermark

I want to watermark, reduce weigth, resize and change format for selected videos. 
Also I need to keep quality as high as it possible.

Now what I have:

```
ffmpeg -i prepared/video.mp4 -i units/video_watermark.png -filter_complex overlay=10:10 -codec:a copy moved/video_test.mp4
```

and I'm watermarking video, but the quality drops a lot. Also I have:

```
ffmpeg -i prepared/video.mp4 -s 1280x720 -b 512k -vcodec mpeg1video -acodec copy
```

but also I need to reduce weight also as lot as possible. The reconstructed videos will be shown as movies online. My question would be - is it possible to do it one line and change format to .mp4?

PS. I have constructed command:

```
ffmpeg -i downloaded/movie/movie.avi -c:v libx264 -acodec libfaac -b:a 64k -preset ultrafast -vf "movie=units/video_watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=10:10 [out]" -movflags faststart prepared/movie.mp4
```

but it returns me error:

```
ffmpeg version 2.7.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
  configuration:
  libavutil      54. 27.100 / 54. 27.100
  libavcodec     56. 41.100 / 56. 41.100
  libavformat    56. 36.100 / 56. 36.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.100 /  1.  2.100
Unrecognized option 'preset'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Comment: You need to include the **complete** console output for the last command.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard added it above.

Answer (score 0):

You can not preserve the original quality of the input source while you try to decrease the size of the file. Still you can adjust the properties to get this done until human eye can not recognize the quality difference. Well, to answer your question you can watermark, reduce file size(reduce quality) and re-size the input video in one line of command.

For this you need to use `filter_complex` to chain all the required filters accordingly. To watermark you can use [`overlay`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#overlay-1) filter and position it on the video. [`scale`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#scale-1) filter will re-size the video or image to its specified width and height. Importantly to adjust the quality of the final output you can use [`crf`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#crf). Also you can specify frame rate and bit rate of the video explicitly if you need more control over the file size adjustment.

```
ffmpeg -y -i input_video -i input_image -filter_complex "
[0:0]scale=1280:720[scaled];
[scaled][1:0]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2[vout]" 
-map [vout] -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -movflags faststart output_video
```

- `scale` filter will adjust the video(first input) to 1280x720. You can find more scaling options [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling%20%28resizing%29%20with%20ffmpeg).
- `overlay` filter will position the watermark image on the scaled video at its centre.
- You have to choose an appropriate [codec](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html) for encoding and here `libx264` is for mp4 output.
- Also you can adjust the `crf` value until it result a satisfiable output.

The error you have mentioned does not appear here for your command. Hope your FFmpeg version has some issue. Include full uncut console out put to analyse it further.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It looks like a good answer, but I'm getting now error `Unrecognized option 'crf'.`

Comment: include the full uncut console output for this command in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The `ffmpeg` configure line is missing `--enable-libx264`, so your build has no support for encoding with libx264.

Your options:

- [compile](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu), or
- [download a static build](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/), or
- [use mc4man's PPA for 14.04](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media)

Comment: but when I try to install it, it says that it is installed already - http://pastebin.com/Di6RNL0a

Comment: @ArnasPečelis Installing `libx264-dev` won't do anything to help. I already listed three options that will fix your issue.

Comment: so I should to reinstall ffmepg?

Comment: @ArnasPečelis You need to use a build that supports libx264 if you want to use that encoder. Any of the three options listed should provide that.